# React transform object in array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to transform a firebase object to an array like this :

here is a link to the fiddle with an example https://jsfiddle.net/vfra1yp5/

```
0: Object { first: "https://google.com", last: "google" }
to 
[
      {
        first: "https://google.com",
        last: "google",
      },

    ]
```

I have tried

```
var res = Object.keys(alllinks).reduce((acc, elem)=>{
  return {
    first : alllinks[elem].first,
    last : alllinks[elem].last
  };
},{});
```

This is how i get data from firebase

```
get(child(dbRef, `links/${dummy.prefix}/links/links`)).then((snapshot) => {
  if (snapshot.exists()) {
    const dummy = snapshot.val();
    setAlllinks(dummy)
  } else {
    console.log("No data available");
  }
}).catch((error) => {
  console.error(error);
});
```

Comment: `0: Object { first: "https://google.com", last: "google" }` The 0: at the start of this makes me think it's already part of an array or array-like. Can you show us how you're getting or creating `alllinks`?

Comment: Ok, that helps a bit, but i'll need to know what the data structure of alllinks is. Maybe do `console.log(JSON.stringify(alllinks))`, and show the result.

Answer (score 0):

You could assign your object with index like keys to an array.

```js
console.log(Object.assign([], { 0: 'foo', 1: 'bar' }));
```

Comment: Hi, i am looking for an object like this ```   const availablelinks = {

    links: [
      {
        first: "dnh75n",
        last: "10",
      },
      {
        first: "456def",
        last: "4",
      }
    ]
  };```  I am using this code to add initalValues to antd dynamic form

Comment: @likewho, you have already an array inside. please add an example of the given data and wanted result to the question.

Comment: Hi, all added here https://jsfiddle.net/vfra1yp5/

Answer (score 0):

Try this maybe:

```
var res = Object.keys(alllinks).reduce((acc, elem)=>{
  return {
    first : alllinks[elem].first,
    last : alllinks[elem].last
  };
}, []); // changed to empty array
```

Comment: nope, still the same result

Comment: I did some more editing and I made it change something  and now i have a little bit of progress:

Comment: var res = Object.keys(alllinks).reduce((acc, elem)=>{
    return {
      first : alllinks[elem].first,
      last : alllinks[elem].last
    };
  }, []); // changed to empty array
  const availablelinks = {
    links: [res]
  };
  const itemInputs = availablelinks.links.map((item) => {
    return {
      first: item.first,
      last: item.last,
    };
  });
  console.log('-.', itemInputs)
and this logs :
Array [ {…} ]
0: Object { first: "https://google.com", last: "google" }
first: "https://google.com"
last: "google"
<prototype>: Object { … }
length: 1
<>: Array []